# Loading an object in ServletContext (application scope)

Tags: spring, tomcat, plugins, struts2, struts

I would like to put two small constant objects (one `TreeMap` and one `ArrayList`) somewhere in the `ServletContext` of a Struts2 webapp (running under Tomcat 6), such that those objects may be accessible from any JSP, through the Application Scope.

Under Struts1, I would have used one of those startup "`plug-in`s" (defined in `struts-config.xml`). Is there an equivalent way of achieving the same result with Struts2?

Alternatively (and maybe even better), since my webapp uses Spring configured in Tomcat with Spring's `ContextLoaderListener`, can I rely on Spring instead?  For instance by creating a bean that declares some appropriate "`ApplicationAware`" interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take 2:
Implement the ServletContextAware interface on one of your spring beans and just do the necessary modifications to the context. If necessary do it in a @PostConstruct annotated method because then your bean is complete at the time you update the servletcontext.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the @PostConstruct annotation.  Nice touch!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take 3:
You might want to check out [Spring Servlet Context scope](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/custom-servlet-context-scope-module.html)

Answer (score 0):

If this was my application (and we're using a fairly similar architecture), I'd inject a singleton spring bean into the base class of my struts2 controller class, but all my jsp's have controllers and all share a common base class.

Comment: To be honest, I love Struts2, but I avoid OGNL as much as I can (too slow!)---prefering to rely on EL if possible.  Also, I would rather not re-inject the same constant objects on the ValueStack with each new request through an interceptor... (That's what you had in mind, isn't it?)